# Find and replace particular multiplication of factors in big multiplication

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have a sum of terms where each is a multiplication of several factors. For example my expression in `FullForm` is

```
expr = Plus[Times[Derivative[1][a][x], Derivative[0, 1][z][t, x]],
 Times[R, z[t, x], Derivative[1][a][x], Derivative[0, 1][\[Sigma]][t, x]],  
 Times[2, R, a[x], Derivative[0, 1][z][t, x], Derivative[0, 1][\[Sigma]][t, x]],  
 Times[Power[R, 2], a[x], z[t, x], Power[Derivative[0, 1][\[Sigma]][t, x], 2]],   
 Times[a[x], Derivative[0, 2][z][t, x]], Times[R, a[x], z[t, x], Derivative[0, 2][\[Sigma]][t, x]], Derivative[1, 0][z][t, x],   
 Times[R, z[t, x], Derivative[1, 0][\[Sigma]][t, x]]]
```

I want to know if in any of the terms I have a multiplication of the form

```
Times[z[t, x],Derivative[1][a][x]]
```

and replace it with another expression in that case.

I am stuck even trying to find my particular multiplication. I have tried with

```
Cases[expr, Times[z[t, x],Derivative[1][a][x]],\[Infinite]]
```

But since the exact expression I am looking for does not appear in the full form I only get

```
out  = {}
```

As a start **I would be happy if I could only find if my desired factor appears in any term**. Then once I can do that it would be even better to replace it, but let us go one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr /. Times[p___, Derivative[1][a][x], z[t, x], q___] :> Times[p, newexpr, q]
```

Replace `newexpr` as desired.

Note the triple underscore on patterns `p___` and `q___`, which means something like: "This is a pattern which may contain any number of elements in sequence, if it even appears at all." This allows us to match forms like `Times[a'[x], z[t,x]]`, `Times[..., a'[x], z[t,x]]`, and `Times[a'[x], z[t,x], ...]` simultaneously. This is largely just required because `Times` tags agglomerate together if they end up next to each other, so it's difficult to predict how large they are going to be. Because *Mathematica* does various things to put them into a canonical ordering and considers `Times` commutative, however, it shouldn't be an issue with what order you specify the replacement in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Replace` with simpler pattern:

```
Replace[expr, s_. Derivative[1][a][x] z[t, x] :> s newexpr, All]
```

> (a^′)[x] (z^(0,1))[t,x]+newexpr R (σ^(0,1))[t,x]+2 R a[x] (z^(0,1))[t,x] (σ^(0,1))[t,x]+R^2 a[x] z[t,x] (σ^(0,1))[t,x]^2+a[x] (z^(0,2))[t,x]+R a[x] z[t,x] (σ^(0,2))[t,x]+(z^(1,0))[t,x]+R z[t,x] (σ^(1,0))[t,x]

```
 TeXForm @ %
```

> $a'(x) z^{(0,1)}(t,x)+R^2 a(x) \sigma ^{(0,1)}(t,x)^2 z(t,x)+2 R a(x) \sigma ^{(0,1)}(t,x) z^{(0,1)}(t,x)+R a(x) \sigma
>    ^{(0,2)}(t,x) z(t,x)+a(x) z^{(0,2)}(t,x)+\text{newexpr} R \sigma ^{(0,1)}(t,x)+R \sigma ^{(1,0)}(t,x) z(t,x)+z^{(1,0)}(t,x)$

Comment: Can I just ask what the s_. stands for?

Comment: @I.C. `s_.` is the pattern that stands  for the `Default` argument ( for `Times` it is 1).  So `s_. foo` matches both  `5 foo` (where a multiplicative factor (5) is there) and `foo` (where the multiplicative factor is the default argument of `Times`, i.e. 1). Hope this helps.